# Passing a variable to a compiled handlebars template (expressjs)

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass a variable to a handlebars compiled template, but I get a blank instead of the right value, even though the console log the right object. I think I am doing some kind of silly mistake, but I've tried a lot and couldn't find the right method.

My script file:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var textTemplate = $("#text-template").html();
    var compiledTextTemplate = Handlebars.compile(textTemplate);

    $('#getText').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        function successCallback(responseObj){
            console.log(responseObj); // I get the right object here
         $("#target").html(compiledTextTemplate(responseObj));
        };

        $.ajax({
        url: "/users/user/get",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response){
                successCallback(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

My view:

```
<div id="target">

</div>

<input id="getText" type="button" value="Get Text">

<script id="text-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <div>
        Your text is here >>> {{text}}
    </div>

</script>
```

When I click the button, I get a blank in the variable, but the console log this object:

```
Object
done: false
text: "Testing your text 1."
__v: 0
_id:"599cb206d86e536924a6cce9"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved just putting a backslash before my value:

```
\{{text}}
```